# Convert Datetime into date data type in SQLserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, timestamp

I have to remove time stamp from a datetime datatype in SQL server and want to keep the output data type as date with this format -> mm/dd/yyyy (This outpu should be displayed as date data type not as a string data type ). I am using SQL server  2012.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to go into a bit more detail. Do you have a table that you're trying to change the data type of? Are you simply trying to change this in a select statement?

Comment: Thanks for your time Rich, Its a date column from the date dimension table. since it is a datetime column , i see the timestamp.  i dont want to see the timestamp in my output and want to see the date in this format -> mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Ok cool,  check Gordon's answer. I think that should cover it

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server, a `date` is essentially a `datetime` with no time component. You can do the conversion simply by doing:

```
cast(datetimecol as date)
```

Both, though are stored using an *internal* format. The output format is controlled by internationalization settings (or the database default).  You can output either type of column as a *string* whose format is mm/dd/yyyy by using conversion format 101:

```
select convert(varchar(10), <col>, 101)
```

The output is then a string with the format you want.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I want the output type as date without the time stamps in mm/dd/yyyy format

Comment: @Drake . . . Then focus on converting the value to a *string* not a *date*.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CONVERT(date, [FieldName]) ?

Please find documentation on this and CAST() [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms187928(v=sql.110).aspx).

Comment: yes i did, so with this approach the data type is date and i dont see the timestamp but it gives me the date in  this format -> yyyy-mm-dd,

Comment: CONVERT(date, [FieldName], 101)